# mysql update column, value from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables, Y2018 and Y2017, like this:

**Y2018**

```
total_revenue: 300
1Y_growth_total_revenue
```

**Y2017**

```
total_revenue: 200
```

I would want to update Y2018 table, and

```
set 1Y_growth_total_revenue = 100.00 * Y2018.total_revenue / Y2017.total_revenue -100
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thank You

Carlo

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for the update/join syntax. Presumably, both tables have another column that can be used to join related records, so:

```
update y2018 y8
inner join y2017 y7 on y7.? = y8.?  -- put the relevant column names instead of "?" here
set y8.`1Y_growth_total_revenue` =  100 * y8.total_revenue / y7.total_revenue - 100
```

Comment: update Y2018 y8 inner join Y2017 y7 on y7.? = y8.? set y8.`1Y_growth_total_revenue` =  100.00 * y8.total_revenue / y7.total_revenue - 100;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? = y8.? set y8.`1Y_growth_total_revenue` =  100.00 * y8.total_revenue / y7.tota' at line 1

Comment: YUPPY!!!!! update Y2018 y8 inner join Y2017 y7 on y7.id_azione = y8.id_azione set y8.`1Y_growth_total_revenue` =  100.00 * y8.total_revenue / y7.total_revenue - 100;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1